# How to tokenize a text in lucene 3.0.3

Tags: lucene.net

I need to translate this code from lucene.net 2.3.2 to 3.0.3.

This code works fine in 2.3.2 but in 3.0.3 the method tokenStream.Next() does not return a token but a boolean. What I need to understand is where to read the token object when next() returns true.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("the house id red");
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream("", stringReader);
Token token = tokenStream.Next();
while (token != null)
{
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(token.TermText()); 
 token = tokenStream.Next();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TokenStreams in Lucene 3+ can now represent a whole set of values (called attributes) for each position in the stream. So you need to modify your example to be attribute aware...

```
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        var stringReader = new StringReader("the house id red");
        var tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream(string.Empty, stringReader);
        var termAtt = tokenStream.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
        while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(termAtt.Term);
        }
```